# trying to reference 1 sub folder from another sub folder

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm horribly frustrated, ugh, i would have thought this be simple...maybe I'm wrong.

I have a parent folder [parent], in that parent folder I have:
index.html [childCSS][childPAGES][childJS][images]
index.html makes a link to [childPAGES]references.html (references.html found in folder childPAGES)
references.html then links to a refCss.css which is found in [childCSS]
refCss.css has a background image call to [images]background.gif. 
yet they can't seem to find each other. 
I have identified that the routing for css isn't loading (i did background-color= #somefunkypurple and it didn't paint it purple)...so its not reading the css file. question is...why...

so html goes like this:

```
index.html
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="./childCss/stylesheet.css"/></head>
further down in code
<a href="./childPAGES/ref.html">
```

now in childPAGES/ref.html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type:"text/css" src="../../childPAGES/stylesheetB.css"
```

but it doesn't locate the file...further within the file:

```
/childCss/stylesheetB.css 
    background-images: url('../../images/background.gif');
```

background.gif isn't found either or displayed...i have no idea what i'm doing wrong...maybe i should use href?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are just going too far up the path with the "../".

Have you tried using:

```
link rel="stylesheet" type:"text/css" src="../childPAGES/stylesheetB.css"

background-images: url('../images/background.gif');
```